# jQuery regex replace return replacing word

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string (url) like this:

```
https://8.random.url.com/g/DFGTER5675/test1/undefined/codec/
```

Here is my regex:

```
/https\:\/\/(?:.*)\/g\/(?:.*)\/(?:.*)\/(.*)\/codec\/(?:.*)/gi
```

And my code:

```
var string = "https://8.random.url.com/g/DFGTER5675/test1/undefined/codec/";
var myRegexp = /https\:\/\/(?:.*)\/g\/(?:.*)\/(?:.*)\/(.*)\/codec\/(?:.*)/gi
var match = string.replace(myRegexp, "OMEGA3");
```

When I do `console.log(match)` it returns only "OMEGA3". What I want is just my string with "undefined" replaced by "OMEGA3". What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex with capturing groups and back-reference:

```
url = url.replace(/(https?:\/\/[^\/]*\/g\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/).*(\/codec\/)/gi, '$1OMEGA3$2');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fZ9Q00/1)

Answer (score 0):

why not use `/undefined/gi`

```js
var string = "https://8.random.url.com/g/DFGTER5675/test1/undefined/codec/";
var myRegexp = /(https\:\/\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/).*?(\/.*?\/)/gi
var match = string.replace(myRegexp, "$1OMEGA3$2");
console.log(match)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick help, because undefined can be any other word

Answer (score 0):

You have the use of the capture group backwards. You should be capturing the parts of the pattern that you want to keep, not the part you want to replace. Then use `$1`, `$2`, etc. to copy those to the replacement.

You also have several non-capturing groups that aren't needed at all.

```
var myRegexp = /(https:\/\/.*\/g\/.*\/).*(\/codec\/)/gi
var match = string.replace(myRegexp, "$1OMEGA3$2");
```